# Disable the configuration tool in Zsh

Tags: debian, zsh, configuration

When there is no `.zshrc` file in a user's home directory and `zsh` is started, an interactive configuration utility is run instead of directly giving access to the shell prompt.

I set up `zsh` to be the default shell on my Debian Wheezy systems. Therefore every newly created user gets `zsh` as login shell if I do not change that manually. Also there is a default `.zshrc` in `/etc/skel`, so all regular users on my system have a copy of the file in their home directory. This is not the case for system users.

When I now change into a system user (for example the user for a specific network daemon) via `sudo` or `sh` I run into the configuration tool, because these users have no `.zshrc` in their home directories.

It doesn't feel right to place a `.zshrc` into each and every daemon's home directory, which also would be a pain to setup and maintain on a lot of systems. But I still wouldn't want to downgrade to a less comfortable `bash` for these users.

Is there a way to disable the `zsh` configuration tool without having to create a `.zshrc` file in the user's home directory? Additionally a way to setup a single file to be the system-wide default `.zshrc` for all users which don't have one would be nice too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from: http://www.zsh.org/mla/users/2007/msg00398.html

```
The shell then executes code in the file
scripts/newuser in the shared library area (by default
/usr/local/share/zsh/<VERSION>/scripts/newuser).  This feature can be
turned off simply by removing this script.  The module can be removed
entirely from the configured shell by editing the line starting
"name=zsh/newuser" in the config.modules file, which is generated in the
top level distribution directory during configuration: change the line to
include "link=no auto=no".
```

and `/etc/zsh/zshrc` is sourced by every shell that has the `interactive`,`rcs`, & `globalrc` options set. (which most interactive zsh processes do)

---

or add `zsh-newuser-install() { :; }` in `/etc/zsh/zshenv`
Which has the obvious side-effect of users not being able to use the function until they undefine yours.

You can refine that by adding a test of the UID.

```
if (( EUID < 1000 )) && (( EUID != 0 )); then # or whatever the highest daemon uid on your system
  zsh-newuser-install() { :; }
fi
```

Comment: Thanks. But isn't there a way without modifying such a file? I guess if upstream updates it, my Debian package manager will overwrite it.

Comment: updated my answer.

Comment: Could you please explain that. What does Privileged do and why will it only be called for users with IDs above 999?

Comment: -lt == Less than, the option will only be set if the uid is less than 1000, most daemon user accounts are under 1000. && `man zshoptions | less -p 'Shell State'`

Comment: `setopt Privileged` doesn't disable the configuration utility and I don't read that out of the manpage either. And the case that the `newuser` file being modified back to it's original state by the system package manager already happened once since your original post.